# Android navigation drawer(provided by Android studio default)

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

When I press navigation menu item change it's color yellow till pressed when release it's come into default.I did not write any code explicitly for setting these things sudden it happens. How can I stop this?please help.
here is my code.
Main Layout-

```
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_users"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_users"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_users_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Menu for navigation view-

```
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view"
    >

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_satellite"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_satellite_black_24px"
            android:title="@string/satelliteView" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_terrain"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_terrain_black_24px"
            android:title="@string/terrain_nav" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_power_settings_new_black_24px"
            android:title="@string/logout_button" />


    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/communicateNavLine">
        <menu
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/shareNavButton"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="@string/aboutNavButton" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

java code -

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    textViewNavHeader =(TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.text_nav_view);
```

this is happening when I click the first item-

[image]

After that when release it's ok

[image]

Comment: did you try looking at the code.

Comment: Sure, many times

Comment: if you look into the code you should understand whats happening and you can change things later to suit your needs

Comment: if I can then I did not come here.

Comment: If you want helps here, you need to post your full Activity as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add custom `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // set item as selected to persist highlight
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                    // close drawer when item is tapped
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                    // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
                    // For example, swap UI fragments here

                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: `setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`... It's already in the question